# How do you encode iPhone/iPod Touch videos with ffmpeg?

Tags: video, iphone, ipod, ffmpeg

There are lots of suggested parameter lists out there for ffmpeg to encode iPod Touch video, but I thought I'd subject the question to SuperUser.com to get some good answers.

How do you encode iPod videos with ffmpeg?

**The best answers should explain why they are using specific parameters.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is maybe not *exactly* what you want, but I would recommend using [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr) for doing this, which is a free, multi-platform and easy video encoder with special profile for iPhone / iPod.

Comment: Looks like a great app. I didn't know it was mutli-platform. It's got a command-line interface as well, so I'm happy.